# NoMethodError - undefined method `strftime` for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rubygems, strftime

I am trying to use the gem 'strftime' in my Ruby project. Here is how I am using it in my code:

TaskController:
class TasksController < ApplicationController

```
    get '/tasks' do 
        Task.all.to_json(methods: [:date_format, :category])
      end
    
      get '/tasks/:id' do 
        Task.find(params[:id]).to_json
      end
    
      post '/tasks' do 
        category = Category.find_by(name: params[:category])
        task = Task.create(
          description: params[:description],
          completed: false,
          due_by: params[:due_by],
          reminder: params[:reminder],
          category: category
        )
        task.to_json(methods: [:date_format, :category])
      end
    
      patch '/tasks/:id' do
        task = Task.find(params[:id])
        task.update(
          completed: params[:completed],
          reminder: params[:reminder]
        )
        task.to_json
      end
    
      delete '/tasks/:id' do
        task = Task.find(params[:id])
        task.destroy
        task.to_json
      end
    
      delete '/categories/:id' do
        category = Category.find(params[:id])
        category.destroy
        category.to_json
      end

end
```

Task Model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base 
    belongs_to :category 

    def date_format
        due_by.strftime("%a, %b %-d %Y")
    end

  
end
```

When I start my rake server, I get the following error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `strftime' for nil:NilClass
Did you mean?  strfd:
```

I am not sure why this is coming up with undefined method. Do you see any problems with the code? Thank you!

Comment: How did you `require` the gem?

Comment: The [`strftime` gem](https://github.com/saturnflyer/strftime) is a special-purpose gem that provides a list of formats matching a given example outcome. It has nothing to do with your question or error (and if you don't use `strfd` or `Strftime::Directives` in your code, you probably don't need the gem). You are calling the built-in [`strftime` method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Time.html#strftime-method) on a `nil` object, hence the `NoMethodError`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your `due_by` is `nil`, no value is set on the particular record you are showing.

You must have a handling for this case or make sure `due_by` is always present by having a presence validation (or have a db validation on top).

One solution to handle `nil` `due_by` is this:

```rb
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    def date_format
        due_by&.strftime("%a, %b %-d %Y") # By adding `&.`
    end
end
```

Comment: Not "most probably"; the error message tells us that `due_by` returned `nil`. When `due_by` is `nil` do you think it's better to return `nil` (by using the safe navigation operator) or to raise an exception?

Comment: Return `nil` vs raise an exception, will depend on the requirements of the system. Displaying `nil` is one solution. Can also be to return a default value. We don't know much of the system requirements.

If `due_by` is expected to always have a value, for me, in general, it's better to have a presence validation and to ensure it in DB level to have a not null constraint, instead of having something like `raise EmptyDueBy if due_by.blank?` in the method.